# Group HTML by heading hierarchy

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I'm looking for a way to transform HTML into a data object of text and arrays according to the heading hierarchy, something like this:

```html
<h1>Title 1</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum 1</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum 2</p>
<h2>Title 1.1</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum 3</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum 4</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum 5</p>
<h3>Title 1.1.1</h3>
<p>Lorem Ipsum 6</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum 7</p>
<h2>Title 1.2</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum 8</p>
```

To translate into something like this:

```js
{
 "Title 1": [
  "Lorem Ipsum 1",
  "Lorem Ipsum 2", {
   "Title 1.1": [
    "Lorem Ipsum 3",
    "Lorem Ipsum 4",
    "Lorem Ipsum 5",
    {
     "Title 1.1.1": [
      "Lorem Ipsum 6",
      "Lorem Ipsum 7"
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "Title 1.2": [
    "Lorem Ipsum 8"
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Any ideas on a library or methods I can look into to do this efficiently?

Comment: Is the HTML from a DOM or a String?

Comment: I will read a string from a file.

Comment: Your result is not valid JSON or JavaScript. Did you mean to use object literals instead of arrays?

Comment: You are right, I should have ran it through JSONLint first. It is now valid.

Comment: have you at least tried?) 
If you loading it from file, and have tag "javascript", i suppose you using it not in the webpage, but in some console app on node.js?